# Gradle searches for ormlite in wrong maven location?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, compilation, ormlite

The problem occurs in IntellJ 14.1.4 Community Edition. Gradle builded project fine until today, same code builds fine on other machine.

**I am getting this error:**
"Could not find ormlite-core-4.48.jar (com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/j256/ormlite/ormlite-core/4.48/ormlite-core-4.48-4.48.jar"

For some reason gradle searches for 4.48-4.48.jar instead of just 4.48.jar. File is on the maven repo.

I am using gradle wrapper v2.3.

Dependencies part of my gradle:

```
ext {
   ...
   ormlite_version = "4.48"
}

dependencies {
   ...
   compile("com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:${ormlite_version}")
   compile("com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:tests:${ormlite_version}")
   compile("com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:${ormlite_version}")
   compile("com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:tests:${ormlite_version}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed below tests dependencies fixed the issue:

```
com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:tests:${ormlite_version}
com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:tests:${ormlite_version}
```